# Meaning of "本ノック"?

Tags: meaning, words, phrases, loanwords

I've seen some books with "本ノック" in the title, such as "Python実践データ分析100本ノック" and "有機化学1000本ノック 反応機構編" but can't figure out what it actually means.

I've also seen it used in a sentence like below:

> 実話100本ノックよ!!

For context, the speaker above is trying to prove to someone that ghosts exist, so they're saying something to the effect of "having 100 true stories."

It seems to be a counter used to make what's being counted sound more impressive than it actually is, but I have no idea.

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8D%83%E6%9C%AC%E3%83%8E%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF/

Comment: 野球のノックで自然に理解できる命名ですが，とくに情報学系の100問のドリルを100本ノックと呼ぶ流行としては，知ってる限りでは2012年に遡る[言語処理100本ノック](https://nlp100.github.io/ja/about.html) が一番古くかつ有名で，データ分析100本ノックはその流れではないかと思います．これはもともと東北大の研究室が由来のようです．

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [baseball jargon](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF) (see ３) for a type of *[fielding practice](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8D%83%E6%9C%AC%E3%83%8E%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)*, but in this context the same term is used to mean *repeated practice* or *drill* in general.

Thanks to **goldbrick** for clarifying the baseball jargon.

Comment: One last question before I accept this as the answer. The whole batting practice fits helpful books perfectly, but what about the sample sentence in the OP, `実話100本ノックよ!!`? How does practicing fit here? Or is it a different meaning this time? For context, the speaker is trying to prove to someone that ghosts exist, so they're saying something to the effect of "having 100 true stories."

Comment: Oh you're right, I looked over that part. I'm guessing it means *100 examples of true ghost stories* or something, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah, I see. So for the second part of my question, it really does seem to act as a counter. Alright, I'll wait a bit for further answers on the second part, but if no more are posted, I'll accept this one. Thanks again!

Comment: (千本)ノック is a type of fielding practice (守備練習) rather than batting practice (打撃練習).

Comment: @goldbrick thanks, I'll update my answer